# Perspective transform on UILabel

Tags: uilabel, calayer, catransform3d, catransform3drotate

I'm trying to add some perspective on a `UILabel`, to make it display as if it's painted over an angled face.

Here's my test label:

[image: Desc]

And after applying the transform:

[image]

My code:

```
@implementation MyViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.f, 250.f, 100.f, 30.f)];
    label.text = @"Hello";
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [label tiltDegrees:20.f];
    [self.view addSubview:label];
    [label release];
}

@end


@implementation UIView (Perspective)

-(void) tiltDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees {
    CATransform3D aTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    CGFloat zDistance = 100; // affects the sharpness of the transform
    aTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -zDistance;
    aTransform = CATransform3DRotate(aTransform, degrees * M_PI / 180.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    self.layer.transform = aTransform;
}

@end
```

I'm stuck with a bunch of problems:

1. The text inside the label doesn't seem to apply the transformation in the same way as the `UILabel` itself does. It's out of frame (clipped), not centered, and the geometry doesn't seem right. Maybe size is wrong too?
2. It is blurred. How could I apply the transform on the text vector *before* it is rasterized. I think that would produce crisp results.
3. I can't seem to work out the coordination between `zDistance` and the `degrees` of rotation, so that they result in a correct perspective. How can I calculate `zDistance` correctly based on `degrees`?

Any help to solve (1) (2) (3) would be greatly appreciated.
Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you already solved this, but the problem is basically that your text label is passing through the gray layer behind it, hence why it seems to clip in the middle of the text.

Translate the text layer towards the camera to solve this problem.